# ImportError: No module named defaults

Tags: django, google-ajax-search-api

I am using django 1.9 version and I wanted to implement ajax search in my application. In the documentation it is says to add the urls to the root url patterns.

```
url(r'^ajax_search/',include('ajax_search.urls')),`
```

Then I am getting an import error as follows:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_ajax_search-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/ajax_search/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
ImportError: No module named defaults
```

Can any one help me solve this issue?

Comment: Please check the updated answer to make your urls working with current package.

Answer (score 3):

`django.conf.urls.defaults` [has been removed from Django 1.6 onwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-6).

[`django-ajax-search`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ajax-search) package was last updated in 2013. The package has not been updated for a long and will not work smoothly for Django 1.9

Either you can find another package or you can manually update it.

Comment: Can you please explain how to update it manually. Is it a simple process?

Comment: @SwathiPantala - Manually updating would be a lengthy task. I'd suggest to look for another package.

Answer (score 0):

`django.conf.urls.defaults` is deprecated in Django 1.4, later removed in Django 1.6. Read [this](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/539). And the package you are using has the `urls` not compatible with Django 1.9. According to the Django 1.9 [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) you should define your `urls.py` as,

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

**UPDATE:**

You can modify your `urls.py` as below to make this working,

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from ajax_search import views as as_views

ajax_search_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^xhr_search$','as_views.xhr_search'),
    url(r'^search/', 'as_views.search'),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ajax_search/',include(ajax_search_urlpatterns)),
]
```